# Peaks in the circle chaos game

Tags: algorithms, fractals, chaos-theory, chaos-game

The [chaos game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game) is a random walk that steps halfway between your current position and a set of predefined points. If the points are on an equilateral triangle, the resulting set is Sierpinski's triangle. I wanted to see what would happen if the points were chosen uniformly from a circle and the result is pretty interesting:

[image]

It looks like there are two peaks in the radial density. If you make a histogram of the radial density and multiply by $1/r$ (to account for the expected spreading in 2D) you get two peaks around 0.35 and 0.60.

[image]

Is it possible to derive the location of these peaks, and maybe even the full radial distribution function?

Comment: please question what does it mean exactly "the points were chosen uniformly from a circle"? ... I mean, for the classical Chaos Game you have a triangle as you said, so you have three points, but how many points did you selected from the circle? (e.g. 100 points, 1000 points?) I am trying to understand that point. Thanks!

Comment: @iadvd at each step of the algorithm, I selected an angle uniformly at random from $[0, 2\pi]$. Using this point, I took a step 1/2 between my current position and the point on the circle.

Comment: I don't understand this enough to write an answer, but this seems very relevant: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1047603

Comment: I'm surprised there is still no answer. This is a fascinating question. @Hooked did you pursue this further?

Comment: You can reduce this to a 1D problem with $x_i \in (0, 1)$ with the update rule $$x_{i + 1} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x_i^2 + 2 x \cos(\alpha) + 1}$$I was also able to work out a reasonably nice expression for the conditional density function $p(x_i, x_{i + 1})$ for $x_{i + 1}$ given $x_i$ by turning the problem into a Markov process. But I think the steady-state density function sought after probably does not have a particularly nice form, elliptic integrals keep popping up. It may be possible to get to its derivative though.